# Use of "reference" element in @ApiResponse annotation in swagger to refer response samples

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I need to show the response example value with respect to each code in Swagger UI, I'm using Spring Boot + springfox-swagger2

Comment: What version of springfox?

Comment: springfox.version - 2.6.0 and i have tried to refer the response samples like this :-  @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", reference="../response.json#/userProfileManager/createUser/200'")

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the "reference" attribute is not been read by during the generation of the swagger file (see https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1705)